# How to automatically shift remaining cols in Bootstrap after deleting a col

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am displaying a set of card in a grid using Bootstrap. After I delete a card using `$('#someId').remove();`, the card dissapeared but the page is now left with a 'hole' of the deleted card.

I am looking for a way to automatically shift the remaining cards to the left/up so that the hole is filled with the remaining card. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use something like masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: A suggestion would be, in your "remove a card method", to grab the parent and walk through the children and reset their position

Comment: How are your `col`s set-up? When you delete the col the grid should adjust to fix the gap: http://www.bootply.com/117586

Comment: I'm using many `div.col-md-6` in a `div.row`. Your snippet is  exactly what I'm looking for. Please copy it as answer here and I will accept your answer.